# Check if tie in count of lists using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

States have cities. I need the state with most cities only if there is no tie. Tie means top 2 states have the same number of cities.

```
var stateWithMostCities = _states
  .OrderByDescending(_p => _p.cities.Count())
  .Take(2)
  .ToList();
```

Now I can check if the city count of first state = second state and determine if there is a tie. However iam asking if this can achieved on the same line shown above using takewhile, skip and other creative uses of linq. Thanks

Comment: " only if there is no tie." how do you define the `else` condition? what do you need else?

Comment: What happens if there is a tie at the top? Do you get the next two?

Comment: I would suggest to group by the count of cities. If you find more than 1 entry for the Max count you have a tie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var stateWithMostCitiesWithoutATie =_states.GroupBy(_p => _p.cities.Count())
                                           .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Key)
                                           .FirstOrDefault(g=> g.Count()==1? g.First():null);
```

The key is, as @Mong Zhu pointed out to Group by the counts of cities, after that you can order by desc to get the max, and if the max group has more than one then you have a tie

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @octaviocci, i had to change line 3 to  .Selectt(g=> g.Count()==1? g.First():null).ToList().FirstOrDefault() due to some weird linq suntax error I could not figure out. Just fyi for others.

Comment: No EF. Error was something like "Error CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return.."

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use `Aggregate` over ordered states:

```
// the state with maximum cities; null in case of tie
var stateWithMostCities = _states
  .OrderByDescending(state => state.cities.Count())
  .Take(2) // at most 2 items to analyze     
  .Aggregate((s, a) => s.cities.Count() == a.cities.Count() ? null : s);
```

But I doubt if you should do this: comparing top `2` states is *more readable*.

Comment: Thanks. Yes manual compare is more readable if this is the only way. However since linq chaining is supposed to me more readable i was going on the lines of sort list->takewhile()..got stuck here.

Comment: If you call `Take(2)` before calling `Aggregate()` it is more efficient, and you can then   write the aggregate as `Aggregate((a, s) => a.cities.Count == s.cities.Count ? null : a);`

Comment: @Henrik Hansen: nice optimization! Thank you

Comment: And this should then be the most efficient of the answers.